# Best way to secure an API key in Vanilla JS and Django

Tags: javascript, django, api, django-rest-framework, websecurity

I am building a simple webapp in **Django** which makes use of ***Google Places API***. The **API is called from main.js file**, and the **data is displayed on the page**.

Right now, the main.js file looks like this:

```
...
const apikey_gmaps = "AIzaSyDMjUwEt0bumPTVt1GpfQHrxyz";
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key="+**apikey_gmaps**)
  .then(...
...
```

I want to secure the API key, since I don't want everyone to be use and share my credentials, and break my bank. I have been reading about it lately, and I am able to use ***.env*** file in Django(Python) using the **Decouple** library. **I want to use the .env variables in the main.js file.** The only solution that I could find was to use **dotenv**, but that requires NodeJS.

**Is there any way to pass the API key from .env to Django and then from Django to main.js? Is there a better way of achieving this?**

Comment: why not call the API from backend and then transfer its results to the frontend?

Comment: For that I need to alter a lot of code. Moreover, the data is passed to other functions in main.js.

Comment: If the request is made via the frontend then the api key will be accessible via the browsers devtools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't secure it if you are calling it from the client-side. What you need to do is create a view to abstract the key.

In views.py:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def gmapAPI(request):
    lat = request.GET.get('lat', 'default_fb_value')
    long = request.GET.get('long', 'default_fb_value')
    apikey_gmaps = "#KEY_OR_GET_FROM_ENV";

    url = f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={lat},{long}&rankby=distance&key={apikey_gmaps}'
    r = requests.get(url)

    print(r.json())
    return Response(r.json())
```

In urls.py add:

```
...
path('maps_api/', views.gmapAPI, name='maps_api'),
...
```

In main.js:

```
    ...
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var targetUrl = (`website/maps_api/?lat=${lat}&long=${long}`) 
fetch(targetUrl)
  .then(...
...
```

Please note that this will make the process of digging up the key very difficult, but the key will still be discoverable, and a good/bad hacker can still get it.